# Subtract char of digits like normal integers

Tags: java, string, subtraction

I have two strings which can be seen as time stamps:

```
String min="2017-04-15 13:27:31";
String max="2017-04-15 13:40:01";
```

Assume we want to find out the time passed from first time stamp to the second one. If there was only the time and no date included, I could get it using my following code:

```
                String[] partsMin=min.split(":");
                String[] partMax=max.split(":");
                int diffZero=Integer.parseInt(partMax[0])-Integer.parseInt(partsMin[0]);                
                int diffOne=Integer.parseInt(partMax[1])-Integer.parseInt(partsMin[1]);
                int diffOTwo=Integer.parseInt(partMax[2])-Integer.parseInt(partsMin[2]);
                diffInSec=diffZero*3600+diffOne*60+diffOTwo;
```

So here is the question. How to get the job done while there is a date within the time stamp?

Comment: You could use the regex `(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})` and extract `$1`, `$1`, `$3`

Comment: Are you familiar with the Java 8 `DateTimeFormatter` class?  This is kind of what it's for.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem no i am not.

Comment: @BackSlash didnt work out.

Comment: Right, sorry, I got distracted answering someone else's question.   The correct class to use is `DateTimeFormatter`, which kind of replaces the (now obsolete) `SimpleDateFormat`.  You could look up the [Javadoc for that class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to see how to use it.  Or, you can look at the answers by @StimpsonCat and @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ, which both give the correct solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the java date time libraries (even the old `Date` class would be fine for this) to parse the string into a proper object.

Depending on the date time library you chose you can then look at the difference between them. The simplest would be something like:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
 Date date1 = sdf.parse(str1);
 Date date2 = sdf.parse(str2);
 long differenceInSeconds = (date2.getTime()-date1.getTime())/1000;
```

The new Java 8 time classes would also allow you to do this and would be better to learn going forwards. I can't remember the syntax for that off the top of my head though.

Comment: just a small Q. why did you divide it by 1000?

Comment: I have to add that `DateFormat` are expensive objects to initialize, if one is intended to be used several times, it would be best to store it somewhere. However, as the format tend to change its locale when it is used and is not thread-safe, it is a bit tedious to safely use. The `SimpleDateFormat` javadoc explains that. The java 8 `DateFormatter` tries to address that issue (by being thread-safe) but comes with other annoying stuff...

Comment: @lonesome get `getTime()` gives the time in milliseconds, thus the difference will be in milleseconds as well. Dividing it by 1000 gives you the diff in seconds.

Comment: @JeremyGrand are you telling me that if there are like 10K of time stamps, using the above code will give wrong answers?

Comment: @lonesome No. You will get the correct answer each time if you use the code above. He's talking about limitations of SimpleDateFormat (which is why I create a new one each time). You can't create one SimpleDateFormat and then use it from multiple threads safely. So long as it is only ever used from one thread you are fine though.

Answer (score 2):

I would construct LocalDateTime instances from it. 
Then i would get the milliseconds from it and substract startTime from EndTime.
What is remaining are the milliseconds passed between the two. A DateTimeFormatter is helpful as well for this purpose.

```
String strMin = "2017-04-15 13:27:31";
DateTimeFormatter formatterTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime dateTimeMin = LocalDateTime.parse(strMin, formatter);

String strMax = "2017-04-15 13:40:01";
LocalDateTime dateTimeMax = LocalDateTime.parse(strMax, formatter);

long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(dateMin, dateMaxto);
long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(dateMin, dateMax);
```

If you want to get the milliseconds:

long millisPassed = dateMax.toEpochMilli() - dateMax.toEpochMilli();

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in your code:

```
int diffZero=Integer.parseInt(partMax[0])
```

is the same as doing:

```
int diffZero=Integer.parseInt("2017-04-15")
```

that is generating an Exception(NumberFormatException)

you should better try to **PARSE** those strings min and max into a date

## Edit:

you can inspect your code/ variables: and see that splitting to ":" is not giving you back the correct array since the element at index 0 is holding more information than you need...

[image]

but as I said before, you are going on the wrong path, dont re invent the wheel and look how practical will get using the APIs that java has for us:

```
String min = "2017-04-15 13:27:31";
String max = "2017-04-15 13:40:01";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime dateTimeMin = LocalDateTime.parse(min, formatter);
LocalDateTime dateTimeMax = LocalDateTime.parse(max, formatter);
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dateTimeMin, dateTimeMax);
long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(dateTimeMin, dateTimeMax);

System.out.println(days);
System.out.println(minutes);
```

Comment: The OP knows that: He is asking how to extract only the hour/minute/second part even if a full date is supplied

Comment: it gives error. because that is not a correct integer.

Comment: @BackSlash that wont work cause it is not a correct integer. if it would work, there would not be such question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with replace all the other part of your String like this :

```
String[] partsMin = min.replaceAll("\\d+-\\d+-\\d+", "").trim().split(":");
String[] partMax = max.replaceAll("\\d+-\\d+-\\d+", "").trim().split(":");
```

Answer (score 0):

use SimpleDateFormat to parse the date string, and do operation on Date result, you will get right value. This works well for date between '2017-02-28 23:59:59' and '2017-03-01 00:00:01'

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date1 = format.parse("2017-02-28 23:59:59");
Date date2 = format.parse("2017-03-01 00:00:01");

long time1 = date1.getTime();
long time2 = date2.getTime();

long diff = time2 - time2; // should be 2000
```